# campagin tracking in Omniture using DTM

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am trying to understand if my s.campaign setup in DTM is working correctly. Here is my setup. I have two sites under a single domain. e.g.

www.domain.com
service.domain.com

We have a PPC campaign with a cid=12345 running. An end user visit the site using the following URL

www.domain.com/somelandingpage/page.html?cid=12345

I have a data element called "campaign", which collects the data from the URL param and store it to the data element and I have set it to store the value for the "session" in DTM. I then have a global setting (AA setting for the property) for campaign where I use %campaign% to store the value.

As the user visit the page (url with cid param), I can see I am capturing the campaign value in the digital pulse debugger and all is good. As soon as I click on any other link on "www" or "service" site e.g. NO cid url param. I see digital pulse debugger is not capturing the "campaign" value.. even though I have set the data element to be valid for the entire user session. Also note I have populated the campaign variable also in the individual rules level e.g. rule being fired on the "service" website. Does it mean Omniture is not capturing my CID data? or do I need to remember the value for the "visitor" . in DTM instead of my current "session". What is the best practice here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you trying to get DTM to pop your campaign variable with the value on every page? When you pop `s.campaign` with a value, you only need to do it once, and Adobe Analytics will associate that campaign code to all the rest of the data moving forward, until whenever you set it to expire in the Adobe Analytics interface.

Comment: Actually, I am very new to AA and DTM in general also we have campaign that runs and the url goes directly to "service" website. But you are correct as I have put the campaign settings under "Gloabl - general settings" I shouldn't need to populate it in pages. @CrayonViolent so all I have to do is to remove the individual page settings and I should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crayon Violent is correct. The Campaigns variable in Adobe Analytics is an e-Commerce Variable (that's why it's listed as v0 in your debugging tools), and the entire purpose of e-Commerce variables, what sets them apart from traffic/prop variables, is that they only need to be set once and then they'll act like a virtual cookie for that user. Repeatedly populating an eVar like this defeats the purpose, and can actually be worse than redundant. If the value that you are re-populating ever morphs into something new, then the original value you set won't get credit for whatever happens after the change.

Inside of your Adobe Analytics admin console (Report Suites -> [select report suite(s)], Edit Settings -> Conversion -> Conversion Variables , you'll see how this eVar is configured. It's the very first one on the page, called Tracking Code. By default it's set to allocate all credit to the Most Recent (Last) value received, so that's why you want the value collected on the landing page to be the Last one, giving your user time to convert and grant credit to that value.